# Implementing fibonacci using dynamic programming in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to implement the Fibonacci sequence using dynamic programming.
It shows an error. What's wrong here?

```
def fibo(n): # n is the nth Fibonacci no. in the sequence
    fib = {} # dict to store earlier values
    for k in range(1, n + 1): # iterating each time
    if k <= 1 : 
                f = 0
    if k == 2 : 
            f = 1
    else:
        f = fib[k - 1] + fib[k - 2] # looking up in the fib{}
fib[k] = f
return fib[n] # returns the nth Fibonacci number

n = int(input('Enter n = '))
print('%dth fibo no. is = %d' %(n, fibo(n))) # calling n printing
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the error message as well.

Comment: First, you should make sure your indents in this question match your indents in the program. Python is very sensitive to indents in your code, and it will help us to determine whether your errors are logical or syntactic

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume your initial error was caused by your indentations. When indented properly, your code runs without errors.

Since you'll be performing the same operation at `k == 1` and `k == 2` no matter the value of n, it makes more sense to assign those values outside the loop, and start your loop later.

```
fib = {1: 0, 2: 1}
```

After this change, and after correcting your indents, your function resembles the following:

```
def fibo(n):
    fib = {1: 0, 2: 1}
    for k in range(3, n + 1):
        f = fib[k - 1] + fib[k - 2]
        fib[k] = f
    return fib[n]

n = int(input('Enter n = '))
print('%dth fibo no. is = %d' %(n, fibo(n)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! Indentation was not the problem really. Since this is my first time in stack overflow, I didn't know how to edit the code  here. The problem was with if / else I guess.